# Cursor assign only being set after a function is finished

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to set the cursor of my program to the *busy* cursor while a large function finishes, but it doesn't seem to update the cursor until **after** the function finishes. My code is:

```
self.__root.config(cursor="wait")
self.__root.update_idletasks()
# do heavy function
# self.__root.config(cursor="")
```

I've also tried this with `self.__root.update()`, but still no luck. The program will hang so it can do the function, and then returns with the cursor I asked for **before**

Comment: Can you post a mcve?